# Encode a message in an MS Word document through double space with a macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to hide a string of characters within the clear text of a word document by inserting a double-space before each word beginning by the successive letters of this string with an MS Word macro.

The following macro works, but

1. it always restarts at the top of the document rather than loop till the end of the document is reached, and,
2. the selection automatically jumps to the next occurrence of the same letter after each replacement of a space by a double space (before searching for the next letter in the string).

For clarity, here is what I'm trying to achieve: to encode the string "hello" in the text of a word document, I

- start at the top of the document;
- search for the first word in the document beginning by "h" (the 1st letter of the string; doesn't need to be case-sensitive);
- replace the space before this 1st word with 2 spaces;
- search for the next word beginning by "e" (the 2nd letter of the string; doesn't need to be case-sensitive);
- replace the space before this 2nd word word with 2 spaces;
- and so on with each following occurrence of a word beginning by the following letter of the string;
- then, once the last letter of the string ("o") is reached, loop at the first letter of the string; and
- repeat the above until the end of the document is reached (the string must be "encoded" as many time as possible in the text).

  Of course, the original document must be single-spaced, and the string could be longer than just "hello".

I tried the following macro:

```
Sub DoubleSpaceEncode()
'
' DoubleSpaceEncode Macro
' Encodes a message in an MS Word document through double space
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "( [Hh])"
        .Replacement.Text = " \1"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    With Selection
        If .Find.Forward = True Then
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
        Else
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        End If
        .Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
        If .Find.Forward = True Then
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        Else
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
        End If
        .Find.Execute
    End With
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "( [Ee])"
        .Replacement.Text = " \1"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    With Selection
        If .Find.Forward = True Then
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
        Else
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        End If
        .Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
        If .Find.Forward = True Then
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        Else
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
        End If
        .Find.Execute
    End With
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "( [Ll])"
        .Replacement.Text = " \1"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    With Selection
        If .Find.Forward = True Then
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
        Else
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        End If
        .Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
        If .Find.Forward = True Then
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        Else
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
        End If
        .Find.Execute
    End With
    With Selection
        If .Find.Forward = True Then
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
        Else
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        End If
        .Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
        If .Find.Forward = True Then
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        Else
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
        End If
        .Find.Execute
    End With
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "( [Oo])"
        .Replacement.Text = " \1"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    With Selection
        If .Find.Forward = True Then
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
        Else
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        End If
        .Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
        If .Find.Forward = True Then
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        Else
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
        End If
        .Find.Execute
    End With
End Sub
```

Needless to say, this macro was recorded in MS Word.

How do I solve problems 1 and 2 above (and possibly simplify this macro)?

Answer (score 1):

This was a fun thing to program.  This is MY approach.  You seem to be good at learning from code.
I think you were wrong to use "wdFindContinue".

```
Option Explicit

Sub DoubleSpaceEncode()
  Selection.HomeKey wdStory ' start at beginning
  Do While doWord("Hello")
  Loop
End Sub

Function doWord(zword$) As Boolean
  Dim ipos&
  For ipos = 1 To Len(zword)
    If Not doLetter(Mid$(zword, ipos, 1)) Then Exit Function ' ends
  Next ipos
  doWord = True
End Function

Function doLetter(letter$) As Boolean
  Selection.Find.ClearFormatting ' necessary?
  If not Selection.Find.Execute(" " & letter, False, False, False, False, False, True, wdFindStop, False) Then
    Exit Function ' ends
  End If
  Selection.Collapse wdCollapseStart ' add a space
  Selection.TypeText " "
  Selection.MoveRight wdCharacter, 2
  doLetter = True
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much,
Your version works pretty well, and it loops.